# Why can we exchange the limit sign for continuous functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

I remember vaguely reading somewhere that limit signs can be pulled out and in if the function was continuous. I forget rigorously what that means, does someone remember what this means?

It was something like:

$$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(x \to c) = f(x) \to f(c)$$

or was it something like:

$$ f( \lim_{x \to c} x ) = \lim_{f(x) \to f(c)} f(x)$$

I think intuitively what I want to say is that we can bring in f(x) within the limit (which is a special property for some reason) but I can't find the language to express that:

$$ f( \lim x ) = \lim f(x) $$

is the conceptual idea I am trying to express. Any ideas?

---

Is it just?

$$ f( \lim_{x \to c} x ) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$$

Is this what preserving limits means?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=f( \lim_{x \to c} x )$ or $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N},\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=x;\ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n )$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}x = c,$ so you are just saying $f(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x),$ which is the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous real valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ it holds that for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a $$ it follows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(a) $$

which can thus be expressed as

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(a) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$$