# Prove that the limit of the sequence is $ 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $ a_n = \sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}$. I want to prove that this sequence converges to $ 2 $, is my solution correct?

We'll first prove that $ (a_n) $ is defined for almost every $ n $. both $ (2^n) $ and $ (n^2) $ are positive sequences and we'll notice that $ n^2 = o\left(2^n\right) $. Therefore there exists a $ N $ such that for all $ n > N $, $ n^2 < 2^n $, or in other words, $ 2^n - n^2 >0 $. Therefore, for all $ n > N $, $ a_n $ is well-defined.

$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{2^{n-1}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\cdot\frac{n^2}{2^n} = 2 \cdot 0 = 0 $, which means there exists a $ K $ such that for all $ n^*>K, n^2<2^{n-1} $.

Let $ n > \max\{N, K\} $. $ \sqrt[n]{2^n - n^2} \leq \sqrt[n]{2^n} = 2 \to 2 $ as $ n \to \infty $.

$ \sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2} \geq \sqrt[n]{2^n-2^{n-1}} = \sqrt[n]{2^{n-1}} = \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{2}} $

$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{2}} = \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n}}{\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2}} = \frac{2}{1}=2 $

Therefore, for almost every $ n $, $ c_n \leq a_n \leq b_n $ where $ c_n, b_n \to 2 $ and by the Sandwich Theorem, $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 2 $.

Comment: Certainly correct. What made you not sure of your solution?

Comment: More simply $\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}=\sqrt[n]{2^n}\sqrt[n]{1-n^2/2^n}=2\sqrt[n]{1-n^2/2^n}$

Comment: "*we'll notice that $n^2 = o\left(2^n\right)$*" $\;-\;$ That's ambiguous. You should either prove it, or explain why the result can be used without proof. But "*notice that*" does neither.

Comment: You may use L'hospital rule for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{2^{n-1}}=0$.

Comment: @dxiv It's a result in my textbook, you're right, maybe I should have mentioned that

Comment: This fact does not influence solution correctness, but $a_n$ is defined for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: @BobDobbs L'Hôpital on something discrete?

Comment: @talopl Ok. Then prove it by other method.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct. But why is $n^2=o(2^n)$? Also, what is $n^*$?

We need to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\Large{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$=$0$. We will do it by Sandwich theorem. Notice that $2^n\geq n^3$ for $n\geq 10$. Hence, $0\leq \Large{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$$\leq\Large\frac{1}{n}$, for $n\geq 10$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} 0=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\Large\frac1n$$=0$, by Sandwich theorem $\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\Large{\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$=$0$. In other words, $n^2=o(2^n)$.

We can also compute the limit in the following way as suggested by user:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\sqrt[n]{2^n-n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}2\sqrt[n]{1-\Large\frac{n^2}{2^n}}$$\color{red}=2\sqrt[n]{1-\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\Large\frac{n^2}{2^n}}=2\sqrt[n]{1-0}=2.$

For the justification of the interchange of limit and the function in the red equality, see the [Zest's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940078/why-can-we-exchange-the-limit-sign-for-continuous-functions) here.